# Having problems with batch if statements

Tags: batch-file

I've tried hard to find out what is wrong with my if statements... I probably missed something very obvious and stupid, but I can't find it.

```
@Echo OFF
:Home

set Password= "Pass"
set /p input= Password:

if "%input%" == "%Password%" (
    Echo Password Correct!
    pause
)
if "%input%"  "%Password%" (
    Echo Password Incorrect!
    cls
    goto Home
)
```

This doesn't work either:

```
@Echo OFF
:home

set Password= "Pass"
set /p input=Password:

if "%input%" == "%Password%" goto correct
if "%input%" != "%Password%" goto incorrect

:correct
Echo Password Correct!
pause

:incorrect
Echo Password Incorrect!
cls
goto home
```

Comment: Place opening parentheses on the same lines as the ifs.

Comment: tried that, didn't work... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
@Echo OFF
:Home

set Password=Pass
set /p input= Password:

if "%input%" == "%Password%" (
    Echo Password Correct!
    pause
) else  (
    Echo Password Incorrect!
    goto Home
)
```

3 changes made

1. Removed the quotes from the set Password line - in batch files, that is not necessary & will actually make quotes as part of the variable - so it will compare true only if the user also inputs quotes.
2. Removed the `cls1. Having a clear screen just after printing your error message will mean that you will never see the error message.
3. Change the 2 `if`s to an `if-else`

Comment: Lol i just figured that out and refreshed this page. Thank you for the help, I got it working...